# OpenCV camera calibration(compute [R|T]) with lines instead of points

Tags: opencv, camera-calibration, robotics

I'm working on a football(soccer) robot with [this tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#void%20stereoRectify(InputArray%20cameraMatrix1,%20InputArray%20distCoeffs1,%20InputArray%20cameraMatrix2,%20InputArray%20distCoeffs2,%20Size%20imageSize,%20InputArray%20R,%20InputArray%20T,%20OutputArray%20R1,%20OutputArray%20R2,%20OutputArray%20P1,%20OutputArray%20P2,%20OutputArray%20Q,%20int%20flags,%20double%20alpha,%20Size%20newImageSize,%20Rect*%20validPixROI1,%20Rect*%20validPixROI2)).
My machine has 2 cameras while the ground map has 6 points recognizable in front of the goal.

[image: 2 for the corners and 4 around the goal]
What I'm doing:

1. Take photos and get intrinsic parameters(focal length,distortions);
2. While moving, find the the points and use **solvePnP** to get the [R|T];
3. Use **projectPoints** to get its real coordinate.

As I have tried, (in a chessboard of 6*9 inner corners) 10 points worked fine, but with only 5 I get really bad result(haven't even considered when the vision is bad or when the ball blocks its vision).

I'm thinking about presetting a good [R|T](with a good vision of the full map),and while moving, utilize its old [R|T](as initial approx.) to help get a better [R|T]. But after sometime, as [R|T] gets less accurate, it's unlikely that I'll get the approx. value.

Another solution though, it's try using the lines to generate [R|T]. For example, after detecting a set of points of a line, relate it with x=0 or y=0... and use them to compute [R|T] which probably will generate a better result. Is there a way to do this?

Or I'm getting it all wrong? Any ideas or help are appreciated!

Comment: What you are describing is some kind of sparse slam. I want to know if your robot has two eyes or just one. It seems to me that it only has one eye. Then what does "utilize its old [R|T](as initial approx.) to help get a better [R|T]." mean. Do you mean [R|T] between the initial pos and the current pos?

Comment: I mean constantly computing [R|T] since it's a video input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd like to contribute, but I have some questions about the settings:

*(i.)* I am assuming that the camera is fixed on the robot. Then, the [R|t] changes with respect to the field (reference). Are you tracking the aforementioned points (features) in the field? In such case their rotation and translation changes when the robot moves around the field.

*(ii.)* Have you checked [Hartley's paper](http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~hartley/Papers/cvpr93/Qfromlines/Q-from-lines.pdf) on calibration from line correspondences? This might give you an idea for your second proposal.

Now, with the assumption that I make on item *i.* try camera calibration of each camera independently to obtain the lens and tangential distortion parameters first. These you want to have them fixed when re-calibrating from motion. Using lines seems more viable as they might be robust against occlusions.

*I can edit this answer in case you provide more details and enrich this discussion.*

I would put this as comment, but I do not have enough credit.

Comment: (i.) Yes, but, probably due to too few points, the result can't be used at all; (ii.) I had a brief glance at it, and it indeed looks interesting;  I haven't tried it with both cameras yet, but I will eventually. And thank you so much for the time and ideas! It's actually a really helpful answer! I'll leave it open and give more updated details until I resolve the problem.

Comment: Instead of sticking it with the ground coordination system I changed it to match the relative location from the robot view and left the computation of ground coordination for postprocessing.